# postfix operators linked list generic node iterator

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate through a linked list node iterator. The code has shown no error in compilation, however, the data placed in the linked lists node does not print. Here are the codes.

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ListNode {
public:
    T fData;
    ListNode* fNext;

    ListNode(const T& aData, ListNode* aNext = (ListNode*)0) {
        fData = aData;
        fNext = aNext;
    }
};
```

The ListNodeTemplate to instantiate a Node.

```
#pragma once
#include "ListNodeTemplate.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ListNodeIterator
{
private:
    ListNode<T>* fNode;
public:
    typedef ListNodeIterator<T> Iterator;
    ListNodeIterator(ListNode<T>* aNode);
    const T& operator*() const;
    Iterator& operator++();
    Iterator operator++(int);
    bool operator==(const Iterator& aOther) const;
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& aOther) const;
    Iterator end();

};
```

The ListNodeIterator header file, you can see that the ListNodeTemplate is included in the header file of the iterator.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "ListNodeIterator.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
ListNodeIterator<T>::ListNodeIterator(ListNode<T>* aNode) {
    fNode = aNode;
}
template <class T>
const T& ListNodeIterator<T>::operator*() const {
    return fNode->fData;
}

template <class T>
typename ListNodeIterator<T>::Iterator& ListNodeIterator<T>::operator++() { //prefix
    fNode = fNode->fNext;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
typename ListNodeIterator<T>::Iterator ListNodeIterator<T>::operator++(int) { //postfix
    ListNodeIterator<T> temp = *this;
    fNode = fNode->fNext;
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
bool ListNodeIterator<T>::operator==(const Iterator& aOther) const {
    return (fNode == aOther.fNode);
}

template <class T>
bool ListNodeIterator<T>::operator!=(const Iterator& aOther) const {
    return !(*this == aOther.fNode);
}

template <class T>
typename ListNodeIterator<T>::Iterator ListNodeIterator<T>::end() {
    return *this = nullptr;
}
```

What I identified so far is that postfix operator doesn't seem to iterate the linked list node. The compiler has shown no compile errors.

Here is the main.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "ListNodeIterator.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    typedef ListNode<int> IntegerNode;
    IntegerNode One(1);
    IntegerNode Two(2, &One);
    IntegerNode Three(3, &Two);

    for (ListNodeIterator<int> iter(&Three); iter != iter.end(); ++iter) {
        cout << "Value " << *iter << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So far it print nothing.

My expected output is:

```
Value 3
Value 2
Value 1
```

Any advice on what the issue is and how to improve upon it?

Comment: `end()` should be a member of the _container_, not the _iterator_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only took a brief look.  I can look in more detail later but I noticed 2 things that I have yet to confirm but you may see it immediately once you read it:

1 ) I think you instantiated your list objects in the order:  1 -> 2 -> 3. So if you started you iterator at 3, you have no next node.

2) It seems weird your Iterator class has an end() function.  That's usually something the container will know.  I don't think an iterator should have any knowledge about the rest of the container.  Also in your end(), assigning *this to nullputr is probably clearing everything so when you try to print, you have nothing to print.

Comment: Yes, your second point is correct. I just figured it out just now. Thank you for commenting regardless.